# SQL Query for Where IN condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a situation like this

```
Select * 
from user_post 
where user_id in (select user_id from follow where follow_id=20)
```

This query is working fine, I need to add follow_id 20 also in the where condition... selected user_id plus this user 20 also included in the WHERE IN condition

I tried like this

```
Select * 
from user_post 
where user_id in (select user_id from follow where follow_id=20) AND user_id=20
```

It did not bring the proper result

the query should be like this

```
Select * 
from user_post 
where user_id in (10,15,20)
```

how to do this

Comment: not possible, since you're requiring user_id to have (potentially) two or more different values at the SAME time. e.g. if the inner query returns `42`, then you're saying `where user_id = 42 AND user_id = 20`.

Comment: Provide Sample Data.  Include Expected Results.  Not sure what you're trying to do yet.

Comment: I am trying to display all the user posts whom I am following and also I want to display my own post for that only I had written this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM 
    user_post
WHERE 
    user_id IN ((SELECT 
                    follow_id 
                FROM 
                    follow 
                WHERE 
                    follow_id=20), 10, 15);
```

Comment: @Subramanian - This must solve your problem. [see sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ff02/23)